# Connecting to SAP Business One Database using php

Tags: php, laravel, database, server, sapb1

I have been tasked with creating a PHP website that interacts with a SAP Business One installation. I will need to do things such as:

• Pull inventory and customer data from SAP B1
• Push customer and new order data to SAP B1

The PHP website will be custom written. I have seen some integration tools that work with e-commerce platforms, such as Magento and WooCommerce, but for this project I will be writing the PHP myself.

I do not have any experience with SAP Business One.

I am hoping that SAP Business One has an API or other tools that will allow me to easily interface with it, and push/pull data in a secure manner. The company providing the SAP B1 says I can use "DI API Server".

I obviously need to familiarize myself with all of this, but I am hoping someone with some knowledge of both SAP B1 and PHP can give me a quick overview or some advice on how to proceed. Or at the very least, the assurance that all of this is doable, that writing my own PHP to interface with SAP B1 is not a horrible idea, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP Business One has a DI API or DI Server that you could use for this purpose.

I'd suggest that you get familiar with the SAP Business One SDK Help Center.
It is very helpful, has loads of examples and is a great starting point.

It may or may not be installed, please check with the company providing SAP Business One. If it is not installed, ask them for the SAP Business One download files, and it should live somewhere in the \Packages\ directory.

It is doable and not a horrible idea.

[Screenshot of the SAP Business One SDK Help Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZwxF.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to interact with SAP B1 from outside. I recommend you start with DI API. Just search for the dll Interop.SAPbobsCOM.dll in your SAP business one folder. Add it to your project and start to use it. Use SDK helper from SAP Business one for information of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i would recommend you to use DI Server instead of DI API as it is more compatible with .NET. It may support you with task but in longer run .NET is much better with DI API.
See below to connect with SAP. Always use manager account as SAP allows limited multiple logon with manager account.

now you have to activate COM for PHP -> enable extension php_com_dotnet.dll.

In php.ini you should find something like :

[PHP_COM_DOTNET]

extension=php_com_dotnet.dll

below code will do the job for you.

echo "SBO PHP TEST
";

$vCmp=new COM("SAPbobsCOM.company") or die ("No connection");

$vCmp->server = "DFSI_DEV_2";

$vCmp->CompanyDB = "SCMC_TEST";

$vCmp->username = "manager";

$vCmp->password = "1234";

//$vCmp->language = "ln_English";

//$vCmp->UseTrusted = True;

$lRetCode = $vCmp->Connect;

echo $vCmp->CompanyName;

echo '
';

$vItem = $vCmp->GetBusinessObject(oItems);

$RetVal = $vItem->GetByKey("A1010");

echo '$vItem->Itemname';

echo '
Ready';

?>
Task 1
Pull inventory and customer data from SAP B1
Plain SQL will do the stuff. No SAP login needed.

Task 2
Push customer and new order data to SAP B1

here comes the tricky part.
You can achieve to create Sale Order in SAP b1 directly via PHP but i would recommend you to build a server side queue manager and a middleware

The PHP code will store the order in DB [Middleware]

the server side app will look for new entries in DB and will post entries into SAP using DI API. On successful entry update the middleware

I do have the similar system running and we have large number of field users creating Sales Order using web portal.